# Sonata date range filter

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I have a sonata date range filter

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $filter)
    {
        $now = new \DateTime();
        $filter
            ->add('created_at', 'doctrine_orm_date_range',  array(
                    'label' => 'created_at_long',
                    'input_type' => 'text',
                    'field_options' => array(
                        'widget' => 'single_text'

                    )
                )
            );
    }
```

If I enter the same date, elements with this date are not returned in my list. 
Is there a way to tell sonata do not use strict comparaison and use "less than or equal" and "greater than or equal" operators ?

Answer (score 4):

I think adding a format tag will relax the constraints. Works for (is inclusive) me anyway with the following:

```
'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy'
```

From this currently live/working filter:

```
->add('someField', 'doctrine_orm_date_range', [], null, ['format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'widget' => 'single_text'])
```

Comment: I have added the 'format' tag and it still doesn't work

Comment: Is it possible there's some sort of timezone issue? I've tested this just now on a currently live sonata admin install and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

*I think you should create your own filter extending this one.*

- On the first input, you set a time to 0:00
- on the second input, you set a time to 23:59

*One other way is to use the doctrine_orm_datetime*

**Why**

When you look at the parent abstract class `Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\Filter\AbstractDateFilter` you can read in the `filter` method :

```
 $data['value']['start'] = $data['value']['start'] instanceof \DateTime ? $data['value']['start']->getTimestamp() : 0;
 $data['value']['end'] = $data['value']['end'] instanceof \DateTime ? $data['value']['end']->getTimestamp() : 0;
```

It's like you where looking for something between `day/month/year:00:00` and `day/month/year:00:00`.

Not between `day/month/year:00:00` and `day/month/year:23:59`

Answer (score -1):

check the created_at attribute in the entity and see its name, if it is createdAt and created_at is its name in the DB so you have to change it to:

```
->add('createdAt', 'doctrine_orm_date_range',  array(
                    'label' => 'created_at_long',
                    'input_type' => 'text',
                    'field_options' => array(
                        'widget' => 'single_text'

                    )
                )
            );
```

because the sonata admin could display the attribute by its DB name but it couldn't apply the filter with it :) hope it helps